# Oracle SQL output select result in grid

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if I can improve the process speed of a similar query like the one below:

```
Begin
    FOR r IN (
        select org_id ,name from op_units order by 1
    ) LOOP

        dbms_application_info.set_client_info (r.org_id);

        for x in (
            select PDI.PROJECT_NUMBER, ppv.description
            from PA_DRAFT_INVOICES_V PDI
            LEFT JOIN pa_projects_v ppv ON ppv.project_id = pdi.project_id
            WHERE PDI.CREATION_DATE > to_date('01/07/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        ) LOOP

        dbms_output.put_line(x.PROJECT_NUMBER||'~'||x.description);

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
end;
```

The above query (but with multiple joins and columns) takes a lot of time to finish. I can only imagine that it takes that much due to the dbms_output.put_line

Is there a better way to do it? Eventually to display the results into a gridview

Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of the outer loop? Nothing in the inner query appears to use it. Perhaps it's something that you've redacted in order to sanitise your query so you can post it here? Either way there's little we can do to advise you with so little information.

Comment: The outer loop sets a variable (set_client_info). Other ways the select will not work at all. Its a must to use the dbms_application_info.set_client_info. That loop will be run always 32 times

Comment: The views that I use in the select statements have been configured to only display data based on a variable that is being set by that set_client_info. If I do not use that command, I will not be able to get any row

Comment: Okay, so your actual queries are a lot more complicated under the covers. Really don't know what you expect us to do when all the important stuff is hidden. But for what it's worth, it's not the `dbms_output.put_line` call. That is negligible. It will be down to the expense or executing the inner query, especially because joined views are hard for the optimizer to tune well.

Comment: The main idea is that I run individual queries, without looping them I get the results for every set_client_info in 40-60 seconds. If I run it like tat it takes hours..

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the outer loop, the inner one can be avoided by inserting rows into a (global temporary?) table; once it is done, `SELECT` from that table. Something like this:

```
begin
  for r in (select org_id , name from op_units) loop
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info (r.org_id);

    insert into temp_table (project_number, description)
      select pdi.project_number, ppv.description
      from pa_draft_invoices_v pdi
      left join pa_projects_v ppv on ppv.project_id = pdi.project_id
      where pdi.creation_date > to_date('01/07/2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Once it is done,

```
select * from temp_table;
```

I'd remove `ORDER BY` in the (outer) loop; it'll be executed 32 times only, but - what's the point?

Using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't scale well. If there's a lot of data, you might even run out of buffer. Also, you'll have to wait until everything is being *drawn* on the output. Also, it isn't flexible - you can't sort it, apply filters to it, ... - for every change you'd want to make, you have to run the same query over and over again. But, if everything is stored in a table, you're much more *free* to do stuff.

Comment: should I declare the temp_table? It raises an error that table / view does not exist

Comment: Yes, you should *create* it (using CREATE TABLE statement).